# How to generate Poisson random variables to follow a Gaussian distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

My question is more practical than theoretical. I'm trying to simulate a natural process by generating events randomly. Let's say that I know some particular event happens following a normal distribution with a known *mean* and *standard deviation*.

For example, let's say I know on average I have 100 visitors on my webpage with stddev of 30. Now I want to generate requests to simulate such traffic. As far as I can remember, generating samples for such a process needs to follow the Poisson distribution. In other words, by generating a Poission random variable, I can tell when the next request should be sent. And once I do it that way, the average number of requests I've generated in a second will follow the initial normal distribution I was looking for, as long as:

```
Poisson-Lambda = 1 / Gaussian-Mean
```

My problem is that I don't remember how should I include the standard deviation of Gaussian in this mix! So, here's my question in one sentence:

How can I come up with the time between my events when I have the Gaussian distribution parameters for how many events happen in a second?

Comment: The number of visitors on your webpage does not have (exactly) a Gaussian distribution, because (1) it's discrete rather than continuous, and (2) it is never negative.  Maybe it is approximately Gaussian.  The number of occurrences of a Poisson process of rate $r$ in a time interval of length $t$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda = r t$.  If $\lambda$ is large, this can be approximated by a Gaussian distribution with mean $\lambda$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\lambda}$.  But you don't get to choose the mean and standard deviation arbitrarily.

Comment: I think I've got it the other way around in my OP. It's been a while since I've worked with random variables. Thanks.